# Angular 4 HTTP request from HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, http, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to update `Http` to the newer `HttpClient`.

For JWT refreshing I extended the `Http` class and override the `request()` method(https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750985/2735398).
Now I want to do the same with interceptors.

This is the interceptor I have right now:

```js
export class JwtRefreshInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  public constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        return this.httpClient.post(environment.base_uri + 'auth/refresh', {}).flatMap((response) => {
          // get token from response.
          // put token in localstorage.
          // add token to the request.

          // Do the request again with the new token.
          return next.handle(request);
        });
      }

      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't inject `HttpClient` because I get an error:

```
Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InjectionToken_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

With extending `Http` I could just call `this.post()` because I was working in the `Http` instance itself. But with the interceptors this can't be done.

How can I make an HTTP request inside an interceptor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject `Injector` from `@angular/core` and get the dependency when needed:

```js
export class JwtRefreshInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        const http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);
        return http.post(environment.base_uri + 'auth/refresh', {}).flatMap((response) => {
          // get token from response.
          // put token in localstorage.
          // add token to the request.

          // Do the request again with the new token.
          return next.handle(request);
        });
      }

      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If I import { Injector } from "@angular/core" and then add "private injector: Injector" to the constructor I get the following.....   Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ResponseInterceptor: (?)  --  Do I need to inject it in the app.module somehow?

Comment: I just what i was finding, because i am implementing  a token refresh :O